# RequireJs Module in node always returns undefined when using in a grunt task

Tags: node.js, requirejs, amd, gruntjs

I've a small config file that I need in frontend and in my grunt task.

**js/config.js:**

```
define(function() {
  return [
    {
      id: 'demo',
      displayName: 'Demo'
    }
  ];
});
```

I can load the file in frontend without problems it also work in node. 
    var requirejs = require('requirejs');

```
requirejs.config({
  nodeRequire: require,
  baseUrl: './js'
});   
var config = requirejs('config')
```

But when I try to load the same file in a grunt task it returns undefined:

```
requirejs.config({
  nodeRequire: require,
  baseUrl: './js'
});   
grunt.registerTask('lala', function  () {
  var config = requirejs('config')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the I require requireJs outside of the `module.exports` function. So this works after all:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var requirejs = require('requirejs');

  requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire: require,
    baseUrl: './js/cfe/app/platforms/as'
  });

  grunt.registerTask('lala', function  () {
    var config = requirejs('config')
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. First I've installed requirejs:

```
cd /path/to/code/directory
npm install requirejs
```

Then in my app.js:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
  nodeRequire: require,
  baseUrl: './js'
});   

var config = requirejs('config');
console.log(config);
```

And in the js/config.js:

```
define(function() {
  return [
    {
      id: 'demo',
      displayName: 'Demo'
    }
  ];
});
```

When I run it, I get the correct result:

```
$ node app.js
[ { id: 'demo', displayName: 'Demo' } ]
```

I'm using Node v0.10.1.

Comment: Are you sure about the asynch loading. The docs for node have an example for synchronous require call: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#3

Comment: @AndreasKöberle You are right, I'm sorry. I updated my answer, but everything works for me. Can you reproduce these steps and make sure that the problem is not something else?

Comment: Ok checked it and it runs in a separate file.